# How dpdk disable `CRC strip`, `header split`, `IP checksum offload`, and `jumbo frame support`

Tags: dpdk

In the older version of `dpdk`, the struct `rte_eth_rxmode` has these members.

```
struct rte_eth_rxmode {
    header_split   = 0, /**< Header Split disabled */
    hw_ip_checksum = 0, /**< IP checksum offload disabled */
    hw_vlan_filter = 0, /**< VLAN filtering disabled */
    jumbo_frame    = 0, /**< Jumbo Frame Support disabled */
    hw_strip_crc   = 0, /**< CRC stripped by hardware */
    ...
}
```

But after updating to `dpdk-stable-19.11.3`, these members are removed. According to the [docs](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides-19.11/testpmd_app_ug/run_app.html), the `testpmd` app supports command-line options such as `--disable-crc-strip` but these are not `EAL` command-line options. How can I disable these five options listed above in `dpdk-stable-19.11.3`? Or are these options disabled by default? If so, how can I check these status?

In addition, the member variable `txq_flags` of struct `rte_eth_txconf` is also removed from `dpdk-stable-19.11.3`. How can I set this in `dpdk-stable-19.11.3`?

I haven't used `dpdk` for a long time. It has changed a lot, and I am struggling with these changes. Is there any way suggested for catch up these changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes in DPDK version 19.11 hardware offloads are enabled using a single member field `unit64_t offloads` in `struct rte_eth_rxmode` unlike individual offload parameters as older DPDK versions.

On the other hand [hardware offloads](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides-19.11/prog_guide/poll_mode_drv.html?highlight=offloads#hardware-offload) in 19.11 are divided into per-port and per-queue offloads based on the configuration. For instance user can set per port and per queue based offloads which device supports which can be fetched using `rte_eth_dev_info_get()`.

As shown below `offloads` field in `struct rte_eth_rxmode` and `struct rte_eth_rxconf` are used to set per port and per queue offloads respectively.

```
struct rte_eth_rxmode {
...
/**
 * Per-port Rx offloads to be set using DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_* flags.
 * Only offloads set on rx_offload_capa field on rte_eth_dev_info
 * structure are allowed to be set.
 */
uint64_t offloads;
...
};

struct rte_eth_rxconf {
...
/**
 * Per-queue Rx offloads to be set using DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_* flags.
 * Only offloads set on rx_queue_offload_capa or rx_offload_capa
 * fields on rte_eth_dev_info structure are allowed to be set.
 */
uint64_t offloads;
...
};
```

Note: Device capable offloads are enabled using the macro's `DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_*` flags defined here - [Rx offload capabilities of a device](http://code.dpdk.org/dpdk/v19.11/source/lib/librte_ethdev/rte_ethdev.h#L1084)

For testpmd you can set the offloads as a bitmask from `DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_*` flags, as shown below provided device supports the features,

```
--rx-offloads=0xXXXXXXXX: hexadecimal bitmask of RX queue offloads
--tx-offloads=0xXXXXXXXX: hexadecimal bitmask of TX queue offloads
```

> I haven't used dpdk for a long time. It has changed a lot, and I am struggling with these changes. Is there any way suggested for catch up these changes?

I would suggest you should register to dpdk developments via mailing list (dev@dpdk.org) to know upstream patches/updates.

Answer (score 1):

With DPDK 19.11.3 one can enable the desired features (crc-keep, jumbo, ipv4-cksum, and header split) programmatically by either editing

```
default configuration as

static struct rte_eth_conf port_conf = {
        .rxmode = {
                .max_rx_pkt_len = JUMBO_FRAME_MAX_SIZE,
                .split_hdr_size = 0,
                .offloads = DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_JUMBO_FRAME | DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_KEEP_CRC | DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_IPV4_CKSUM | DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_HEADER_SPLIT,
        },
        .txmode = {
                .mq_mode = ETH_MQ_TX_NONE,
        }
};
```

or modifying the offload features in `port_init` by fetching and comparing the features by

```
port_conf.rxmode.offloads |= DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_JUMBO_FRAME | DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_HEADER_SPLIT | DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_KEEP_CRC | DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_IPV4_CKSUM;
```

note: a handful of NIC support the feature for `DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_HEADER_SPLIT`, so there much likely it will fail in port_init. Use http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/overview.html as a generic guide for offload features.

use https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/testpmd_app_ug/run_app.html#eal-command-line-options for enabling the features in testpmd

- `--max-pkt-len=[size]` - enable JUMBO
- `--disable-crc-strip` - keeps the crc from stripping
- `--enable-rx-cksum` - enables HW checksum (even for IPv4 Checksum)

note: with regards to DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_HEADER_SPLIT looks like it is not added to testpmd as not many NIC PMD supports the same.

if there are features not supported by NIC PMD one can expect error messages like

`Ethdev port_id=0 requested Rx offloads 0x2000e doesn't match Rx offloads capabilities 0x92e6f in rte_eth_dev_configure()`

in order to get more description please run with `--log-level=pmd,8`